# Can't create C# Holographic project in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c#, visual-studio, hololens

I'm trying to start developing for the Hololens 2.

Instead of using Unity to create a 3D app, my intention is to create a "desktop app" with C#.

After installing the [Windows Mixed Reality App Templates](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=WindowsMixedRealityteam.WindowsMixedRealityAppTemplatesVSIX) from the Microsoft Marketplace, I tried to create a C# project but VS gets stuck in the progress bar while creating the project and after several minutes displays the following message:

[image: project creation error]

This issue is somewhat approached in this MS page: [Creating a holographic DirectX project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/develop/native/creating-a-holographic-directx-project), in which it says:

> If your holographic C# project didn't start from the Windows Holographic app template, you'll need to copy the ms.fxcompile.targets file from a Windows Mixed Reality C# template project and import it in your.csproj file to compile HLSL files that you add to your project.

It is clearly a known issue by Microsoft, but that's all there is to it.

Even with VS completely stuck, it does create the files for the project, and all the files mentioned above are present but i does not open properly.

What should I do to make the C# project work? Have anyone else faced this?

**PS.:** The C++ project template works fine.

Thanks.

Comment: Which project template are you selected as the scaffolding when getting started to create an MR app in the Visual Studio?  I try to reproduce this issue with `Holographic DirectX11 App(Universal Windows)` but it works fine for me. Could you check that is there any network management software (such as anti-virus software, Firewall, VPN, etc.) is running on your PC or network Gateway?

Answer (score 0):

When you say you want to create a "desktop app with C#", are you referring to a 2D app or a volumetric app?

2D apps are a breeze, you just create a regular UWP C# project [Blank (App Universal Windows)] and then build and deploy it for ARM64 to your HoloLens 2 and it will just work. No special templates required. Regular UWP apps that run on the desktop also run on the HoloLens. You can do a few things to optimize them for HoloLens and/or Windows Mixed Reality but you don't require any special templates.
See these links for more info:
[Designing for Mixed Reality](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/devices/designing-for-mr) and
[Building 2D Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/develop/porting-apps/building-2d-apps)

If on the other hand you are trying to create a volumetric 3D experience in C# that involves DirectX there is a template in the Windows Mixed Reality templates that leverages SharpDX, look for the "Holographic DirectX11 App (Universal Windows)" the template without the "(C++/WinRT)" trailing text. It is a C# option that leverages the opensource SharpDX wrappers. There is mention of that option near the end of this "Creating a UWP project" section of the
[Creating a holographic DirectX project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/develop/native/creating-a-holographic-directx-project#creating-a-uwp-project) page.